# Can I see code coverage on code executed by headless browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, code-coverage

ATM I'm working on a *small* project with `node.js` + `express` + `mongodb`. The logic is on web, but  is loaded from my node.js server. Something like this in my `index.html`

```
<script src="./app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var debug = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    app.start();
});
</script>
```

My test are **functional** -- meaning that I use a headless browser (`Zombie`) and I get good indications about the coverage with `istanbul`. I tried `blanket` unsuccessfully.

```
process.env['TEST'] = true;
var app = require('../server/JS_TPV.server.js');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var should = require("should");
var Browser = require("zombie");
var browser;
```

Then something like:

```
before(function(done) {
    var populateDB = require('../install/JS_TPV.mongo_db_fill.js');
    populateDB.install(function() {
        browser = new Browser({debug:false, silent:false});
        browser.visit("http://localhost:8080").then(done,done);
        console.log("visited ending BEFORE");
    });
});
```

But since `index.html` file is being accessed and all the `js` files on it are loaded, I think it should show it's coverage too.

Is any way to show this?

Or the only way to do this is by generating an html-kind of test where I check my web functions? (yeah, or with `require.js` and testing all the logic node-style).

Thanks!

Comment: I had to let it go, it's a personal project and I was stuck for too long. I decided to test functions separatelly. Maybe in some future I'll go back to this and update with result.

Answer (score 1):

You can :)

The key points are

1. the code executed by the browser has to be instrumented
2. someone must collect the coverage information

You can find an *example* of this working here: https://github.com/ericminio/yop-promises/blob/master/test/promises.with.browser.spec.js

run in order `npm run cover` and `npm run report` and navigate to coverage folder to find the report. Play around with not running Zombie test to see how that impacts code coverage.

This is one example with Zombie and Istanbul, so it really deals specifically with how those two tools can let you go through the 2 points above.